# Errors after upgrading from Ubuntu 16.04 to Ubuntu 18.04!

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, kernel, updates

After running a `sudo apt update && sudo apt -y dist-upgrade` I got broken python3 packages error (unmet dependencies) but I didn't bother to correct it and rather went for a reboot. After rebooting I wasn't able to login and somehow I found a workaround for that (basically doing ctrl + alt + f4 and typing startx after login) . But now when I do uname -a this is what I get:

```
Linux horcrux 4.4.0-187-generic #217-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 21 04:18:15 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

lsb_release -a results:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

So basically this still means that I have a kernel of Ubuntu 16.04 right? But then my whole GUI is now of Ubuntu 18.04 and also my glibc. Here's what I have tried so far:

- Doing a `sudo do-release-upgarde` but it returns Abort without any error.
- Tried `sudo apt-get -f install` and `sudo apt install --fix-missing` but to not much avail.

Is there any other possible way by which I can fix this issue?

Edits:
ldd --version

```
ldd (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.27-3ubuntu1.2) 2.27
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
Written by Roland McGrath and Ulrich Drepper.
```

apt-cache policy libc-bin

```
  Installed: 2.27-3ubuntu1.2
  Candidate: 2.27-3ubuntu1.2
  Version table:
 *** 2.27-3ubuntu1.2 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.23-0ubuntu11.2 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
     2.23-0ubuntu3 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
```

sources.list.d/

```
aims-ubuntu-sagemath-xenial.list                       ondrej-ubuntu-php-xenial.list
aims-ubuntu-sagemath-xenial.list.save                  ondrej-ubuntu-php-xenial.list.save
cybermax-dexter-ubuntu-sdl2-backport-xenial.list       openjdk-r-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list
cybermax-dexter-ubuntu-sdl2-backport-xenial.list.save  openjdk-r-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list.save
deadsnakes-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list                      pgdg.list
deadsnakes-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list.save                 pgdg.list.save
diwic-ubuntu-hda-xenial.list                           samoilov-lex-ubuntu-aftl-stable-xenial.list
diwic-ubuntu-hda-xenial.list.save                      samoilov-lex-ubuntu-aftl-stable-xenial.list.save
fossfreedom-ubuntu-packagefixes-xenial.list            sublime-text.list
fossfreedom-ubuntu-packagefixes-xenial.list.save       sublime-text.list.save
google-chrome.list                                     system76-ubuntu-pop-xenial.list
google-chrome.list.save                                system76-ubuntu-pop-xenial.list.save
hda-me-ubuntu-xscreensaver-xenial.list                 teams.list
hda-me-ubuntu-xscreensaver-xenial.list.save            teams.list.save
jonathonf-ubuntu-python-3_6-xenial.list                ubuntu-audio-dev-ubuntu-alsa-daily-xenial.list
jonathonf-ubuntu-python-3_6-xenial.list.save           ubuntu-audio-dev-ubuntu-alsa-daily-xenial.list.save
kazam-team-ubuntu-stable-series-xenial.list            webupd8team-ubuntu-java-xenial.list
kazam-team-ubuntu-stable-series-xenial.list.save       webupd8team-ubuntu-java-xenial.list.save
nodesource.list                                        zman0900-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list
nodesource.list.save                                   zman0900-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list.save
```

Here's my command history:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1tGXEvYnnUgxh6Zf9CfIeSPshTIXDL6iFJ5S3m849JLU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Sorry this is unclear You mention `sudo apt -y dist-upgrade` which won't cause a *release-upgrade* unless sources were modified (and then it will likely create python3 errors as you describe because Ubuntu != Debian), but only mentioned the `do-release-upgrade` step which does cause upgrade at the bottom as if it was post-upgrade?  Please clarify as it reads to me like you treated Ubuntu as if it were Debian (which it isn't!; `do-release-upgrade` causes upgrade in a specific order not breaking python in Ubuntu)

Comment: Yes, I randomly followed the first ```apt -y dist-upgrade``` thing as others do-release-upgrade wasn't working out for me. After that I rebooted, fixed the python3 issues using ```sudo apt-get -f install```. And then after that I did ```do-release-upgrade``` as a post-update which failed. I'm actually a noob and when one thing didn't work properly I went and tried another thing which resulted in the issue.

Comment: `apt -y dist-upgrade` will only perform a `full-upgrade` and won't change your release (ie. a xenial release will remain xenial  (if you were only 16.04.5 it would become 16.04.6 but not change to something else); `full-upgrade` or `dist-upgrade` just has fewer restrictions than `upgrade` has).

Comment: Okay, that's something probably which I wasn't aware about. Is there any way to solve the current issue? Like I am seeing the GUI for Ubuntu 18.04 and ```do-release-upgrade``` just seems to abort. Is there any other information I must provide?

Comment: I don't understand why you think you have a 18.04 GUI. 18.04 has GNOME desktop/GUI where as 16.04 uses Unity 7 as it's default GUI, however GNOME was an option for 16.04 (just as Unity 7 is available as an option on 18.04).  Why you think you're on 18.04 is unclear, and sorry I don't understand your issue.  (*which doesn't mean others won't*...)

Comment: Like the homepage shows Ubuntu 18.04 in startup. Also, my current glibc has also been updated to 2.27. My current issue is is there any other way to update my kernel to Ubuntu 18.04 by any way?

Comment: Provide details like `apt-cache policy libc-bin` then, yes 2.23 is expected for xenial (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=libc-bin). 16.04 has two kernel options, GA or the 4.4 kernel and HWE or the 4.15 kernel (which is also the GA kernel for 18.04). 18.04 likewise has two kernel options.. so your talk of kernels is unclear (as unspecific as to whether or not you're talking GA or HWE, as 16.04's HWE kernel is 18.04's GA kernel).  I would check your sources (you should have no mention of *bionic* anywhere!)

Comment: I will add it in the edits of the question. Thank you for your help!

Comment: The `apt-cache` policy shows your sources won't provide that package, so I would check your sources (inc. those in sources.list.d/) AND apt logs, command history to see where you've introduced non-Xenial packages (you're likely to already know). What you've described here won't create your issue, nor what else has been done that has introduced non-Xenial packages & made your system a *fraken* one. You can also use `ubuntu-support-status` (or `ubuntu-security-status`) for clues, but I would base fix on what has been done which we don't know.

Comment: I have made changes in the edits by updating with sources.list.d and my logs file. I did the update on 25th 5:30 UTC. I really didn't understand much of the logs myself and have added the really long logs to the file. Thanks a lot for your quick response!

Comment: I meant for you to search the `/var/log/apt/history.log` looking for a command (which will include GUI commands) that caused the installation of the 2.27-3ubuntu1.2 package.. with intention of also what else was installed and what else was impacted. If pollution (files installed as consequence of whatever action caused that to occur) a fix maybe to fully upgrade yourself to 18.04, or just revert to a prior backup before that change. I didn't want to see that sources.list.d/ directory, my suggestion was to look through all sources including all files in that directory for non-xenial..

Comment: I'm really sorry for the misunderstanding. When I searched ```/var/log/apt/history.log``` I saw the particular 2.27-3 ubuntu1.2 package being installed under the command ```apt -y dist-upgrade```.

Comment: If it was a `dist-upgrade` that caused it to be installed; it was because of improper sources under /etc/apt/ (which should have been revealed with the `apt-cache policy` command... meaning something is missing, or it was via a direct command elsewhere in apt history. From what you've described (which is now circular), something is missing, and a restore of backups would be easiest.  (*finding it in history.log gives you a day/time at least*)

Comment: I just checked my command history, and right before this command I did ```sudo sed -i 's/xenial/bionic/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
``` could this be an issue as well?

Comment: That is the *smoking gun* and would have been revealed if you'd looked in your sources (as suggested). That is used to upgrade Debian, but creates problems with Ubuntu (usually with python3 as Ubuntu relies more heavily on `python3` for tooling thus the Ubuntu specific *release-upgrade* tools that add order to upgraded packages).  I would re-install your system, *I'm likely not to be able to comment again*.  If desktop I'd use *something-else* and no format (of partitions), so data isn't touched.

Comment: Okay. So I used the wrong commands all together. I see then there's no other way other than a clean install then? Anyways, thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: If you re-install using "*something-else*", selecting your existing partitions and **ensure** you don't have format ticked, it'll note your added packages (ie. added after you installed), erase system directories, install, add back your additionally installed packages (*noted earlier*), then ask to reboot.  It won't touch your user files (unless you selected format) and is actually pretty fast. It's what I'd suggest in your case, the amount of work to fix your position will take far longer..

Comment: Okay...I ended up in a rabbit-hole by copy pasting random commands. Thank you for suggestions and help :)!!!